# How to select everything between the " " and save it as a variable?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

In every file is a "`Name`" and it is always written like this:
`name="That isn't the same"`.

Now how can I select everything in between the " " and put it in a variable to replace with another variable? I tried something like this:

```
$stringtofind = 'name="*"'
```

Comment: Please provide a little more context about your input data. Are those HTML or XML files? Also, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I would use Regex:

```
'name="That isnt the same"' -match "`"(.+)`""
$stringtofind = $Matches[0]
```